# Gradle DSL method not found: 'applicationId()'

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error on building the application in Android Studio.

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'applicationId()'
```

build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    applicationId "com.ms.knowursensor.android"
    minSdkVersion 13
    defaultConfig {

        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName "sensorgraph"
            stl "c++_static"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debuggable = true
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
            // use the jni .so compiled from the manual ndk-build command
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

This issue came when i recently update the SDK. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `applicationId` and `minSdkVersion` into your `defaultConfig` closure.